# May this long polling code cause stackoverflow?

Tags: javascript, function, async-await

From https://javascript.info/long-polling :

> A sketch of client-side `subscribe` function that makes long requests:

```
async function subscribe() {
  let response = await fetch("/subscribe");

  if (response.status == 502) {
    // Status 502 is a connection timeout error,
    // may happen when the connection was pending for too long,
    // and the remote server or a proxy closed it
    // let's reconnect
    await subscribe();
  } else if (response.status != 200) {
    // An error - let's show it
    showMessage(response.statusText);
    // Reconnect in one second
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    await subscribe();
  } else {
    // Get and show the message
    let message = await response.text();
    showMessage(message);
    // Call subscribe() again to get the next message
    await subscribe();
  }
}

subscribe();
```

For simplicity, let's assume all `response`s are `200` and flows into the last `else` branch, doesn't it keep calling `subscribe` and never returns to the "top"? Won't it blow the stack if there were enough recursive function calls?

Comment: Luckily, no. Making a recursive algorithm asynchronous with Promises is one way to avoid having the algorithm overflow, had it been done synchronously

Comment: Wow, that closure comes so quickly. I would take a look at the linked question. Thanks.